# How to delete a friend in Parse.com

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform, nsmutablearray

I am trying to remove a friend from my friends page with no success can someone please help?

.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) PFRelation *friendsRelation;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *friends; 
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *unfriend;
@property (nonatomic, strong) PFUser *currentUser;
```

.m

```
self.friendsRelation = [[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"friendsRelation"];

    PFQuery *query = [self.friendsRelation query];
    [query orderByAscending:@"username"];

    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error){

        if (error) {
          //  NSLog(@"error %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        } else {
            self.friends = objects;
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }

    }];

- (void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    PFUser *user = [self.friends objectAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]];
    PFRelation *friendsRelation = [self.currentUser relationForKey:@"friendsRelation"];

    if( 0 == buttonIndex ){ //cancel button

    } else if ( 1 == buttonIndex ){

        if ([self isFriend:user]) {
                   for (PFUser *friend in self.friends) {
                if ([friend.objectId isEqualToString:user.objectId]) {
                    [self.unfriend removeObject:friend];
                    break;
                }
                   }
            [friendsRelation removeObject:user];

        } else {

        }

        [self.currentUser saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeed, NSError *error) {

            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"error %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            }

        }];

}
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

-(BOOL)isFriend:(PFUser *)user
{
    for (PFUser *friend in self.friends) {
        if ([friend.objectId isEqualToString:user.objectId]) {
            return YES;
        }
    }

    return NO;
}
```

The Mutable array is there for adding and removing objects but at the moment its empty i think thats why its not working?
When i press ok i would like to remove the friend from my freindsRelation but at the moment nothing is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like it updates the relation, and so the server, but not the table view.

You should remove the unfriend mutable array and instead remove the friend from the friends array. Then reload the table view.

Comment: how can i do that? as it we can not add and remove from an array

Comment: Change it to mutable and make a mutable copy when you get the results.

Comment: hi thanks, the user removes but then when i come back to page it shows again

Comment: The save completed without error? Do you still see the data on the server?

Comment: why does the username remove from friend and then come back in viewWillAppear, is it because we call self.friends = objects.mutableCopy

Comment: If the data is still on the server then the code either isn't being run to update and save the user or the object you remove isn't actually part of the relation. The code in general looks ok. Add break points to check what is running and when. It's also possible that you have an issue where the data is gone from the server but the app has a cached response for the find which isn't being updated...

Comment: When i remove the `break;` from the if statement it crashesand says `was mutated while being enumerated.'`

Comment: You shouldn't even need a loop, you should only have got to the alert response if the user selected is a friend. And yes, you can't change an array you're enumerating.

Comment: so how can i make the user remove from friends relation and not come back when we reload table of friends

Comment: It isn't clear why you see it come back. Check hasCachedResult on the query to see if caching is an issue. If the data is still on the server then how or what you remove from the relation is wrong.

Comment: PFUser *user = [self.friends objectAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]]; this line has a warning next to it saying incompatible pointer to integer conversion can that be an issue?

Comment: Yes, because you're using an index path instance instead of a number. Didn't notice that before. You want to get the row from the index path and use that.

Comment: `PFUser *user = [self.friends objectAtIndex:[[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] row]];`

Comment: thanks got rid of error but user still keeps coming back, is that because we made self.friends = object.mutableCopy

Comment: No, that is why it is removed from your table view, because that array drives the table contents

Answer (score 0):

Replace
       [friendsRelation removeObject:user];

for

```
 [friendsRelation deleteInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
if (succeeded) {


 }
```